# Forzar descarga o mostrar en otra ventana un pdf utilizando html2pdf

Tags: php, html, ajax, pdf

Me pueden apoyar por favor.

Estoy desarrollando un sistema sencillo para una empresa, quieren generar ordenes de servicio. Es un formulario con diversos inputs que el cliente llena para después generar un PDF con toda esa información.

Se está utilizando htmltopdf https://html2pdf.fr/es/home
El código es sencillo:

```
    <-- formulario con inputs id="generarOrden"-->

    // jquery
    /* Pruebas de formulario de orden de servicio */
        $("#generarOrden").off("submit").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url : "procesos/ordenes.php" ,
                dataType : "json" ,
                type : "post" ,
                data : data ,
                success : function(rD){

                    /* Resultado correcto */
                    if (rD.status == 200) {
                        console.log("Petición correcta");
                    }

                    /* Error en la petición */
                    if (rD.status == 404) {
                        console.log("Algo está mal");
                    }
                }
            })
        });

//archivo procesos/ordenes.php (solo de pruebas)
if (isset($_POST)) {

    // Guardar los valores en variables de SESSION para su uso
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION["ordenDeServicio"][$key] = $value;
    }

    // Tipo de orden de servicio
    $tipo = (isset($_GET["tipo"])) ? "blank" : "filled";
    $orden = new PDF();

    return json_encode(array("status" => 200 , "response" => $orden->generar_orden_de_servicio($_POST)));
    exit();

} else {

    http_response_code(400);
    return false;

}
```

Todo hasta ahí funciona correctamente en realidad, me regresa en el callback el pdf como tal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si puedo abrir esa respuesta de ajax en otra pestaña mostrando el pdf o forzar una descarga, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Answer (score 2):

Para generar el pdf como tal (configuración del **html2pdf**):

```
$contenido=ob_get_clean();
require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');

try{    
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','es', false, 'UTF-8'); // hoja en vertical
    //$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L','A4','es', false, 'UTF-8'); // hoja en horizontal
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Courier'); // Tipo de letra
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($contenido, isset($_GET['vuehtml'])); // Pdf
    $html2pdf->Output($titulo); // Titulo del pdf
}

catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) { echo $e; }
```

Para hacer que **html2pdf** se diriga directamente a **descargar** el pdf en vez de abrir el pdf utilizas:

```
$path="C:/wamp/www/tusistema/archivos/";
$file="archivo.pdf";
$path=$path.$file;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
//header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="archivo.pdf"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archivo.pdf"');
readfile($path);
```

**Nota:** La linea `//header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="archivo.pdf"');` Es para mostrar el archivo en una ventana nueva del navegador, descomentala cuando quieras lograr esto.

**Nota 2:** La linea que logra forzar la descarga sin abrir el documento es: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archivo.pdf"');`